# PL SQL Report function showing wrong number or types of arguments in call to '='

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

```
function CF_OP_QTYFormula return Number 
is 
  v_qty number(10); 
begin  
   select sum(L_QTY) 
     into v_qty 
     from purchase_01   
    where MONTH_YEAR = :P_MONTH_YEAR -1;   
   return v_qty; 
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Where does this `:P_MONTH_YEAR` come from? That is not the correct syntax to reference parameters or variables in PL/SQL. (Plus: you have not defined a parameter or variable named `p_month_year`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this is Oracle Reports which allows you to refer directly to source data columns using `:P_COLNAME` syntax.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, I'm pretty sure that MONTH_YEAR =: P_MONTH_YEAR -1; is wrong syntax. The operator =: it's wrong. The right operator is :=.

Comment: `:=` is the assignment operator, not the comparison operator.

Comment: oh, yeah, i'm sorry. You are rigt.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `:P_MONTH_YEAR` parameter's type to number. 
( assuming you have defined externally this parameter as date, varchar2 etc. )

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've solved the problem and it's working, and I used the below code:

```
function CF_OP_QTYFormula return Number is 
    v_qty number(10); 
begin 
    select sum(L_QTY) 
    into v_qty 
    from purchase_01 
    where MONTH_YEAR = to_date(:PTO_MONTH_YEAR,'dd-mm-yyyy') -1; 
    return v_qty; 
end;
```